# How to get Python WolframClient library to connect with WolframKernel on Linux?

Tags: interoperability, python

My question is similar to the one posted here: [WolframEngine install + wolframclient for Python on Ubuntu](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199083/wolframengine-install-wolframclient-for-python-on-ubuntu). However, this solution is not fixing my problem.

I cannot get the wolframclient library to successfully connect to the WolframKernel that is installed on my machine.

I have installed Mathematica 12.0 (for student) on laptop (Pixelbook).

When I run:

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
session = WolframLanguageSession(kernel='/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.0/Executables/wolfram')
session.start() <-- this call will fail resulting in a socket exception: Socket operation aborted. 

we 'Failed to communicate with kernel'
```

Furthermore, I am able to launch Mathematica from terminal, so there is clearly an activated kernel.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it TCP/IP connection? What's about the firewall permissions? Or permissions for access to folders?

Comment: The WolframEngine uses ZMQ sockets for communication beyond that, I don't know.

The Kernels live in /usr/local/path-to-kernel so I don't think there would be a permissions problem.

Comment: am encountering the same issue with version 13. have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

Note: One way I got around this was my instead pointing to my kernel that Mathematica uses.

`kernel=/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.0/Executables/WolframKernel`

However, this only works because my university has a site license for Mathematica. Therefore, this is not a true solution.